# [Error while Running the Gstreamer Example on Development Kit]; "File descriptor in bad state"

Tags: raspberry-pi, images, multimedia, mediaplayer, bananapi

I'm running a basic application on Orange-Pi DVK with Gstreamer-1.4.0. While running the application it throws this error:

```
AL lib: (WW) alc_initconfig: Failed to initialize backend "pulse"
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_reset: snd_pcm_hw_params(self->pcmHandle, hp) failed: File descriptor in bad state
```

While running on Ubuntu (running on VMware), it works well. Why is this not running properly on the Development kit (Orange-Pi) and how can I resolve this?

Comment: This sounds related - https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/pulse-audio-fails-to-initialize-on-pi/29080.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 forum threads sound like your issue:

- [OF 0.9.0 Rasberry Pi B+ sound problem](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/of-0-9-0-rasberry-pi-b-sound-problem/21667)
- [Pulse audio fails to initialize on Pi](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/pulse-audio-fails-to-initialize-on-pi/29080)

The resolution there was to install Pulseaudio:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Comment: hi, i tried with install pulseaudio...but still the same error:

AL lib: (WW) alc_initconfig: Failed to initialize backend "pulse"
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_reset: snd_pcm_hw_params(self->pcmHandle, hp) failed: File descriptor in bad state

please help.

Comment: Please suggest some better solution....